# Bad instruction error when calling child from firebase in swift 2

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swift2

We are trying to access a child in database, however we are using a string from a previous view brought in by a segue. It keeps giving the error of bad instruction. Only appears after running in simulator. We are looking for a resolution to the error. Thanks!

function from previous view with string:

```
    }
    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! SorDViewController
        if segue.identifier == "secondScreen" {
            controller.textToDisplay = nameField.text
        }
    }
```

code for accessing and uploading data to firebase(error only appears in first function):

```
 import Foundation
 import UIKit
 import Firebase
 import FirebaseDatabase

 class SorDViewController: UIViewController {

     var textToDisplay: String?

     @IBAction func postData(sender: AnyObject) {
         let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL("database URL")
         ref.child(textToDisplay!).child("Type").setValue("Singles")
     }

     @IBAction func postData2(sender: AnyObject) {
         let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL("database URL")
         ref.child("Type").setValue("Doubles")
     }

 }
```

Comment: Are you sure `textToDisplay` isn't nil?

Comment: After pointing that out it is coming out as nil. Thank you. Do you know how we can change this?

Comment: Does `nameField` have any text in it?  If so, you'll need to look at why that value isn't being saved properly.  Either way, you'll probably want to wrap your database call in an `if let textToDisplay = textToDisplay` or something similar to guard against nil values.  And in general, I would be very cautious about force/implicitly unwrapping anything besides `@IBObject`s - if there's a chance of it being nil, you're risking a crash, and if it isn't supposed to ever be nil, you should first see if there's a way to make the variable non-optional.

Comment: Can you post the code where the segue occurs?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick test, try changing your `prepareForSegue` method from this:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! SorDViewController
    if segue.identifier == "secondScreen" {
        controller.textToDisplay = nameField.text
    }
}
```

to this:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! SorDViewController
    print("=> nameField: \(nameField.text)")
    controller.textToDisplay = nameField.text
}
```

and please double check that your `nameField.text` actually has a non-nil value in it :)

Also a good idea to track changes to `textToDisplay` like this:

```
var textToDisplay: String? {
    didSet {
        print("oldValue: \(oldValue), newValue: \(textToDisplay)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried it, however, it led to the same exact error. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: @MitchellMarkoff Also: are you sure you aren't setting `textToDisplay` elsewhere in your `SorDViewController` code?

Comment: Our nameField.text should not have a nil value in it. In the simulator, it is being filled with the name string. The error says "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping". Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @MitchellMarkoff I bet your error is coming from the `textToDisplay!` expression (i.e., `textToDisplay` is nil, resulting in a crash). Now we need to track down why it has a nil value...